# Convert generic type to Half value allocation-free

Tags: c#, .net, generics, half-precision-float

In an application that can write numeric values to a file using `BinaryWriter` I have a class that is typed to the number type that should be used for the file. It looks like this:

```cs
class ValueCollection<T> where T : struct, IConvertible
{
    private BinaryWriter writer;
}
```

The constructor will make sure that only supported types are used as type arguments. (Code not shown here, it's just `typeof(T)` comparisons.)

It has a method that should write such a value to the file writer, that looks like this:

```cs
public void Write(T value)
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(int)) writer.Write(value.ToInt32(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo));
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(long)) writer.Write(value.ToInt64(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo));
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(double)) writer.Write(value.ToDouble(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo));
    // (There are more...)
}
```

That's all fine. But how can I support the `Half` type with this in an allocation-free and non-dynamic manner? This doesn't work:

```cs
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(Half)) writer.Write((Half)value);
    // Cannot convert T to System.Half
```

`IConvertible` and the `Convert` class don't know about `Half` at all. Am I lost here with this shiny new data type being unusable when all other number types work just fine?

I'm targeting .NET 8 and can use all the features there are. But it needs to work in an AOT publishing environment, so no reflection and probably also no dynamics.

PS: The same will come for a read method that uses `BinaryReader.ReadHalf` and should convert it back to `T` to return a value.

Comment: Half doesn't implement `IConvertible`, so it won't satisfy the constraint. What type of solution are you expecting here?

Comment: Hm, good point. I added that interface to allow converting all the other number types. When I try to change it to `Convert.ToInt32()`, it seems to fall back to the method overload with the `object` parameter, which does boxing and allocates memory each time.

Comment: Seems like we need a new `IConvertibleWithHalf` interface that includes the `Half` type besides all the others.

Comment: `HalfToInt16Bits` maybe? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.halftoint16bits?view=net-8.0 `IConvertible` is in any case an interface that doesn't make a huge amount of sense. A lot of types won't convert to a lot of others, and if they do convert it may be lossy or inefficient. You are probably better of special-casing what you need. `Convert` class was made as a hold-over from VB6 twenty years ago, and is advised against.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot immediately use [`System.Half`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.half?view=net-8.0) as type value `T`, as `Half` does not implement the `IConvertible` interface that you request in the constraint.

Since you state that you check the number type in the constructor anyway, you could as a workaround drop that type constraint, and instead implement a custom handler function for every type. You then choose a suitable one during initialization:

```cs
class ValueCollection<T> where T : struct
{
    private readonly BinaryWriter _writer;

    private readonly Action<T, BinaryWriter> _writeValue;
    
    public ValueCollection(BinaryWriter writer)
    {
        _writer = writer;
        _writeValue = typeof(T) switch
        {
            Type t when t == typeof(int) => (Action<T, BinaryWriter>)(object)WriteInt32,
            // ...
            Type t when t == typeof(Half) => (Action<T, BinaryWriter>)(object)WriteHalf,
            _ => throw new NotSupportedException()
        };
    }
    
    public void Write(T value) => _writeValue(value, _writer);
    
    private static void WriteInt32(int value, BinaryWriter writer) => writer.Write(value);
    // ...
    private static void WriteHalf(Half value, BinaryWriter writer) => writer.Write(value);
}
```